# How to scan dynamically added text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to scan all text on a page and selectively create tooltips on pieces of text.  I have working code that does this, but it only works on text that's on the page when the DOM ready event fires.  Since the `.live()` function has been deprecated, we're supposed to use `.on()`, but that function only applies to elements that existed when it was called.  Delegate event handlers apply to both current and future elements, but require the bound event to bubble up to the parent and the `load` event doesn't bubble.

So how can I scan all text--or even all the elements for that matter--as it's dynamically loaded?

**UPDATE:**

Per Makaze's comment, I tried several approaches.  This one seems closest so far, but not quite:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '*:not("script")', function(e){
console.dir(e.target);  //drill in here, I can see the nodeType==3 nodes
//var find = $(e.target);
var nodes = flattenTree(e.target.childNodes, 0);    //recursively get all child nodes
for(var i in nodes){
    var elem = $(nodes[i]);
    var parent = elem.parent();
    var txt = elem.text();
    if(txt!==undefined && !txt.match(/^\s*$/)){
        var refs = txt.match(versePattern);
        if(refs!==null){
            //var i = 0;
            console.log(refs);  //I never see the text node here, but I see it above when I manually drill into e.target
```

The `versePattern` matches as I expect in the static version of this code (which is working correctly), so I don't think that's the issue.  Also, the `'*:not("script")'` doesn't seem to work as I'm still seeing `<script>` tags, but that's a minor thing that I can deal with later.

Comment: by load event do you mean the [ajax function load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or an onload event like window.onload? If you mean the ajax function then you can use the promise that is returned from that call to setup a callback to execute once the load is complete

Comment: The first parameter of `.on()` is an event type. By "load" I mean the [DOM load event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents-h3)

Answer (score 1):

The `MutationObserver` constructor is what you want. Bind it to the parent element or document and filter your mutations from there.

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.addedNodes);
  });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

setTimeout(function() {
  target.appendChild(document.createTextNode('There!'));

  // later, you can stop observing
  // observer.disconnect();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="some-id">Wait for it...</div>
```

**Side note:** You can use `.on()` on the document and use a selector to filter the targets similar to `.delegate()`: `$(parentSelectors).on(types, childSelectors, function)`.

Comment: This method seems promising, but is perhaps incomplete. The `addedNodes` member only contains nodes added as children of the target, so I wrote a flattening function to get all of the descendants of the addedNodes. But when I test this (I'm testing this on Facebook, using `var target = document.querySelector('body');`) I don't see all of the text nodes being added as I scroll down and more content is loaded.  Is there possibly some other mechanism for adding to the DOM that `MutationOberver` would not be able to detect?

Comment: It appears so. You can try [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) for Facebook, which appears to use a complicated scheme to add elements, but also binding the following seems to work, though deprecated: `document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) { console.log(e.target); }, false);`

Comment: You can also add the the `subtree: true` flag to the configuration object. That returns mutations on all children.

Comment: Outputting `mutation.target` instead of `addedNodes` with `subtree: true` results in identical behavior to DOMNodeInserted, but also grabs removals all types of mutations including attribute or value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialized all your textboxes that you want to put tooltip on your js file.

Sample;

```
//Initialize Tooltip
$('#Name').tooltip()
$('#Age').tooltip()
$('#Address').tooltip()
```